# How to make form input and the value table be on the same page with Spring MVC and Thymleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-annotations

I want to insert a set of values and display a list of inserted data on the same page. What should I do in the controller class?

Here are all my codes

#### UserController.java

```java
package com.crud.controll;

import com.crud.model.UserEntity;
import com.crud.service.UserDao;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    private final UserDao userDao;

    public UserController(UserDao userDao) {
        super();
        this.userDao = userDao;
    } 
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String Home(Model model) {
        
        List<UserEntity> users = userDao.findBookAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserEntity());
        return "display";
    }

    @PostMapping("/home")
    public String createUser(@ModelAttribute UserEntity userEntity, Model model) {
        
    userDao.createANewUser(userEntity);
        
    return "display";
    }
}
```

So, this is the page that I want

[image]

Comment: Hi. I think you could just add data in model object in `createUser` method. Or, redirect to `Home` method with `return 'redirect:/home'`. This second solution is better one if it is what you want. Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easy if you update your method as follows:

```
   @GetMapping("/home")
    public Model Home(Model model){
        
        List<UserEntity> users = userDao.findBookAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserEntity());
        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

If you do not need info about inserted user use this:

```
@PostMapping("/home")
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute UserEntity userEntity, Model model) {
        
        userDao.createANewUser(userEntity);
        
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

If you need info about inserted user, you can use flash attributes:

```
@PostMapping("/home")
public RedirectView createUser(@ModelAttribute UserEntity userEntity, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        
        userDao.createANewUser(userEntity);
        
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute ("newUser", userEntity);

        return new RedirectView("/home", true);
    }
```

and in `Home` method use:

```
 @GetMapping("/home")
 public String Home(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
            
            List<UserEntity> users = userDao.findBookAll();
            model.addAttribute("users", users);
            model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserEntity());


            Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = 
            RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
            if (inputFlashMap != null) {
                UserEntity newUser = (UserEntity) inputFlashMap.get("newUser");
                model.addAttribute("newUser", newUser);
            }
 
            return "display";
        }
```

Or you can put `newUser` into `userForm` property to fill out form.

More info about flash attributes: [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-flash-attributes). Maybe there is even nicer way to extract flash attributes in `Home` method.